Using a type variable at the term level
Consider the following GADT, Pin:
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds #-}

module Mcu where

import Data.Kind (Type)
import GHC.Num.Natural (Natural)

data Pin :: Natural -> Type where
  RedLED :: Pin 0
  GreenLED :: Pin 1
  Buzzer :: Pin 2

I would like to know at the term level what the type variable n (of kind Natural) is:
pinOf :: Pin n -> Natural

The following attempt:
pinOf :: Pin n -> Natural
pinOf _ = n

Results in error:

Variable not in scope: n :: Natural

Enabling ScopedTypeVariables and using forall doesn't work either:
pinOf :: forall n. Pin n -> Natural
pinOf _ = n

This results in the error:

Illegal term-level use of the type variable n


Use natVal:
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module Main(main) where

import Data.Kind (Type)
import GHC.TypeNats

data Pin :: Natural -> Type where
  RedLED   :: Pin 0
  GreenLED :: Pin 1
  Buzzer   :: Pin 2

pinOf :: KnownNat n => Pin n -> Natural
pinOf = natVal

main :: IO ()
main = do print (pinOf RedLED)
          print (pinOf GreenLED)
          print (pinOf Buzzer)

This prints:
0
1
2


Excellent answer. The KnownNat constraint may also be eliminated with an exhaustive pattern match, as in pinOf' :: Pin n -> Natural; pinOf' n = case n of RedLED -> pinOf n; GreenLED -> pinOf n; Buzzer -> pinOf n.

Thank you very much.
Don't we still need to enable the extensions GADTs and KindSignatures for specifying the return type of the data constructors and the kind of Pin, respectively?

The program I gave compiles fine with GHC 9.10.1; without any other extensions. But you're right, you probably need some extra extensions when you work these things. I usually wait till GHC tells me to add such extensions.
